# iReport Mistakenly Displaying Summary between Detail Band and Column Footer

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports, ireport

The **problem is displaying summary band incorrectly**. To make it more clear, I will provide some screenshots:

This image is fine.

[image: OK_Image]

My report is 19 pages long. On page 1 to page 18, the bands are displaying their position properly, but when it reached on the last page, I found out that the `Summary Band` is located **between** `Details Band` and the `Column Footer Band`. Now, how can i correctly do it?

This is the image for the last page of the report.

[image: InvalidBandPosition]

If anyone here has an idea how to correctly do it, I badly need your help. This is my first time creating a report in `iReport`.

My client requires me to print a `Page Total` and a `Grand Total` of the report.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you're hitting a bug or not. But perhaps it would solve your problem to put the Grand Total information into the Last Page Footer band instead of the Summary. No?

Comment: it would be a good idea but the problem is I dont know how to add `Last Page Footer`. can you help me on this?

Comment: Adding (and removing) bands is done by right-clicking the relevant band in the Report Inspector panel.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the report option: `Float column Footer`

[image: Float column Footer]

Comment: thank you for the quick reply but unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem. I already set `Float column Footer` to true so the column footer automatically follows after the last record of the report.

Comment: Hummmm... What version are you using (and is your client flexible on the version)? Maybe a bug.

Comment: i'm using a plug-in version (4.5) for netbeans